# What is the proper way to create multiple directives?

Tags: angularjs

Assuming I had a directive that had a d3 chart that would normally replace a div:

Assuming that depending on user events (i.e. clicking an "Add Button") causes a new instance of the directive to be added (i.e. if the button were clicked twice, two instances would be added as such, but its contents would be replaced by the template somehow?) and a "Remove Button" that removes a specific instance of the directive based on the "id":

Without angular I would use jquery append that appends a div with the entire template into it. How can this be accomplished using angular directives?

Note: Usually I would just use:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
   $('.container-div').append('<mygraphic>Other Dom Elements Involved</mygraphic>')
});
```

Though I assume that with the template being defined in the directive I can use:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
   $('.container-div').append('<mygraphic></mygraphic>')
});
```

Though the issue is how do I get mygraphic to be the directive? (On initial page load, angular finds these tags and replaces them with the template. After a page is finished loading and I want to create multiple independent instances of "mygraphic", but using the templates defined in the directive, is there something extra I need to do or some alternative method to add them?

Comment: show some code that would cause the `directive to be added`. Question is too vague without some context

Comment: Updated with more context.

Comment: you need to $compile those elements.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how this would work with a jquery event handler outside of angular?

Answer (score 0):

```
var module = angular.module("app", []);

module.directive("myGraphic", function () {
    return {
        restrict:"E",
        template: "<h1>{{data}}</h1>",
        scope:{
            data:"="
        }
    };
});
module.controller("TestCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.graphics = [];
    $scope.add = function () {
        $scope.graphics.push(new Date());
    }
    $scope.remove = function(index) {
      $scope.graphics = $scope.graphics.splice(index,0);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dVvW8/

Comment: I am not sure how this allows you to dynamically create multiple instances of "myGraphic" using <h1>..data...</h1> let alone remove it. Someone mentioned compile... is that something that should be used?

Comment: Well, In my example, when I click the button my "myGraphic" directive is added. The ng-repeat is doing it for me.
I dont know your template, so I just put some <h1>{{data}}</h1> into it
look the fiddle